Rebuilding RAID1 with Luks after system reinstall
My current Linux Mint 20.3 is soon running out of support, so I figured it's time to install a fresh Linux Mint 22. Currently I have mdadm running two 4TB drives on RAID1 with LUKS. It's been very many years since I set this thing up (and last time while upgrading to Mint 20, I corrupted my superblock rebuilding after install...), so I figured this time I make sure I got my to-do list right, before I proceed with the operation.

First unmount RAID directory


sudo umount /storage (my mountpoint for /dev/md0)


Stop existing RAID Array on source system


sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0

(Install new Linux Mint)

Assemble RAID1 back


sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb


Unlock existing devices


sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 raidcrypt


add /etc/fstab mount


/dev/mapper/raidcrypt /storage  ext4    defaults        0       2

Am I missing something critical? Should this retrieve my RAID1 setup on a new install? Obviously I will be installing the operating system on a different dedicated SSD drive.
If I understood, I definitely need to avoid 'mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb' which would create a new superblock, correct?

Note the low number of followers on the 2 tags you have used. Maybe sort the tag list here by size and add the largest followed tag that is still appropriate?

Thanks, did that! Hopefully someone can verify, before I proceed with the opration.

As long as nothing touches these drives, it will work; otherwise, it will be gone. So it depends on how much you trust the installer to leave things well alone. Additional measure would be to unplug the drives, or run the installer in a VM which has access to the dedicated SSD only, then migrate from VM to bare metal (and then trust the installed system won't wipe the drives as it boots). That's the rabbit hole, it should work, but if you're looking for guarantees, there aren't any. Have a backup.

Thank you! I've always installed RAID drives unplugged, just to be safe. And have a backup, too.

Good luck then, let us know what you discover!

Apparently I can't even get past the start! I tried 'sudo umount /storage', but apparently 'umount: /storage: target is busy.' --- Alright, so I tried 'sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0', but to no avail as it returned 'Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md0:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?'. Finally I tried even closing down my crypted device first by 'sudo cryptsetup luksClose raidcrypt', but I got 'Device raidcrypt is still in use.'

I stopped even my docker if that was keeping the target somehow busy, but no help.

Damn, I'm running out of ideas. I stopped even pCloud process from starting on start-up (my cloud backup), and even disallowed mounting my 8GB swapfile on /storage. (I keep rather on traditional HDD than SSD because they wear down if constantly used.)

Updated original post. /etc/crypttab entry was needed and added link to fix the issue if the RAID device builds as /dev/md127 (or any descending number from that) rather than /dev/md0 (or ascending number)

Better to post an official answer (that is the model here). You can self-accept your own answer (after ~48 hrs(?)) and gain valuable reputation points. Glad you solved your problem. The more tutorial-like you can make your answer, the more general benefit and the more up-votes by others are likely.

I rolled back your edit which added an answer to the question text and tagged the title with "(solved!)".  If you have an answer to your issue, please add it using the answer box at the bottom of this page.  After a while, you may "accept" your answer, which marks the issue as resolved.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer
